# How to set global http proxy settings for apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, jolokia

In Apache Commons 4.3 and onwards, you need to inject your HTTP proxy settings at the `HttpRequest` level - but not globally, in the `HttpClient` itself:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://url");
httpget.setConfig(config);
...

httpclient.execute(target, httpget);
```

The problem is that, in some higher-level libraries, configuration is made by passing a custom-built `HttpClient` instance. **But that doesn't give you access to the `HttpRequest` built inside the API code.**

For instance, in Jolokia (a JMX REST bridge), you create your client like this:

```
J4pClient j4pClient = new J4pClient("http://localhost:8080/jolokia", httpClient);
```

Is there a way to specify an HTTP proxy in this case ? The `http.proxyHost` system property seems ignored and i'd like to avoid creating a full layer of wrapper classes around `HttpClient` and `HttpRequest` to inject the settings during the request creation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use HttpClientBuilder.  It will pull in the system properties for http.proxyHost, http.proxyPort, http.nonProxyHosts.

```
HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();
```

See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html